# PyCharm : Error Saving System Information

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]Error saving system information: C:\Users\npratapa.PyCharmCE2017.2\system\stat\unit.112 (Access is denied)

I keep getting this error message.

Tried restarting PyCharm. Doesn't change anything

Error saving system information: C:\Users\npratapa.PyCharmCE2017.2\system\stat\unit.112 (Access is denied)

I keep getting this error message.

Tried restarting PyCharm. Doesn't change anything

Comment: What are you trying to do? Install it?

Comment: No. I have it installed.

I'm writing code and when I try to run it, I see this error message pop up

Comment: Oh ok, could you maybe edit your question to clarify this?

Comment: Try running pycharm as an administrator?

Comment: Tried running as administrator, Pycharm doesn't run..

Answer (score 2):

Removing the hidden properties for the PyCharm settings folder worked for me.

Comment: Where is the PyCharm settings folder?

Comment: See the screenshot in the question